# Can Resharper unwrap wrapped lines of code?

Tags: c#, resharper

Does Resharper have the ability to unwrap lines that were previously wrapped?
For example I have many of the following lines:

**CONVERT FROM:**

```
dat =
                            CleanDecimal(
                                (from d in lstRecordData
                                    where (d.Acctid == id.Trim() && d.Fscsdsg == "A")
                                    select d.Netperd6).First());
```

**INTO THIS:**

```
dat = CleanDecimal((from d in lstRecordData where (d.Acctid == id.Trim() && d.Fscsdsg == "A") select d.Netperd6).First());
```

Comment: Why? Aside from some formatting issues in what you provided, I find it much more readable than the second example. I'm sure you can write some kind of transform to do this, but are you better off?

Comment: Personal preference I suppose. I find the latter much easier to read and follow. It drastically reduces the scrolling as there are hundreds of these and similar lines. I'm wanting to see more on my screen at one time.

Comment: That one may be slightly easier (for you) for the example, but imagine one that created anonymous objects and had a few inner joins in it. I wouldn't categorically consolidate them...

Comment: Fair enough. The intent was to temporarily reformat the code to facilitate easier debugging.

Answer (score 4):

To fix unwanted line-breaks you have to

- uncheck the setting "wrap long lines" or increase the "Right margin (columns)" first which caused the line-wrap
- then you have to uncheck the "Keep the existing line breaks" to apply these new settings and to "unwrap" the multi-lines to a single line
- then you could execute the "Cleanup Code" action on the whole file by right-clicking it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, go to the ReSharper > Options window.  Under the Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line Breaks and Wrapping, there is a section for Line Wrapping where you want to disable "Wrap Long Lines".

However, as mentioned in the comments, I would not advise doing this over the long run as readability is dramatically reduced by having those statements on a single line.

[image: Wrap long lines option on ReSharper]

Comment: Does this explain how to "unwrap" lines? So consider that resharper has wrapped all lines in a file because the right-margin-columns setting was too small. Now you want to have them all in one line after you've changed that setting. Is that possible?